# I am switching laptops. I host my WP server through MAMP. I want to transfer

Tags: database

I am switching laptops. I host my WP server through MAMP. I want to transfer the entirety of my server to my new laptop so I can sell the old one. 
Should I just install mamp on my new MacBook & transfer the files after the fact? or how should I go about this?
I'd rather not lose any business files, but would like to sell my MacBook Air as soon as possible.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can backup your WordPress website using [UpdraftPlus](http://updraftplus.com) plugin. Make sure you also backup database. 
After setup the WP on other laptop just upload the backup.

Comment: bet bro. Thank you, I appreciate the help. Hope you're having a productive day